# Usage Logs Issues

Tags: logs

I have an issue with my usage logs on one of my SharePoint server. I've got 2 servers:

Server1 = CA
Server2 = WFE

My usage logs is doing fine on server 1 and running the following timer job "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Processing " deletes all expired logs.

The issue is I've got some usage logs on server 2, how do I get the timer job to remove those logs also?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Open Central Administration on your Server 2 and ensure that Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Processing job is not disabled.
- Check the schedule. How frequent is this job set to run on Server 2.
- If all these settings are OK then try restarting your SharePoint Timer Service from Service.msc on your server 2.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I actually did recycle the Timer service and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the timer jobs (that deletes the expired logs) are running on second server. It is obvious but it would be good to make sure that the logs path is same on both server.